# Первый элемент заданного класса после текущего

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно найти первый элемент определенного класса после текущего? Располагающийся в дереве ниже него, но неважно, на каком уровне вложенности. Например, так:

```
<div class = "текущий"></div>
<div></div>
<div class = "искомый"></div>
```

Или так:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class = "текущий"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "искомый"></div>
```

Comment: в общем случае только перебором все элементов, сначала на одном уровне, потом в детях, потом в родителях

Comment: Даже если получится, там будет полная жесть. Лучше не пихать это в селектор и по-человечески поднимаясь циклом наверх проверять.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, в каком виде у вас текущий элемент, но вот повод для раздумий:

```
var i=0;
while($('.класс').eq(i++) != {ваш текущий элемент} );
{искомый элемент} = $('.класс').eq(i);
```

в jQuery так просто элементы сравнить нельзя, это псведокод.
Тоже самое без лишних букв и знаков $, и работает, а не псевдокод:

```
var i=0,els=document.getElementsByClassName('класс');
while(els[i++] != {ваш текущий элемент} );
{искомый элемент} = els[i];
```

Можно еще так, суть та же, но коллег можно напугать:

```
var els=document.getElementsByClassName('класс');
{искомый элемент}=els[++Array.prototype.indexOf.call(els, {ваш текущий элемент} )]
```

Comment: как я понял из вопроса - классы все-таки разные

Comment: @Grundy плохо понял, там конкретно написано - найти первый элемент определенного класса после текущего

Comment: Может быть, меня смутила разметка в вопросе: `<div class = "текущий"></div>` и `<div class = "искомый"></div>`

Comment: я понял, что дан любой элемент документа (как «текущий»), и дано имя класса. Нужно найти первый элемент указанного класса, расположенный в дереве после «текущего» элемента. Т.е. «текущий» элемент никак не связан с искомым классом.

Comment: тогда проще воспользоваться функцией [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) :-)

Comment: @Grundy ну да, проще.. не знал о ней. Мне религия запрещает jQuery пользоваться.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно искать элемент, имеющий указанный класс и расположенный после требуемого. Реализация на "чистом" *JavaScript* без использования дополнительных библиотек.

```
function getNextElementByClassName(element, className) {
    // Проверка элемента и его дочерних (рекурсивно).
    var checkChildren = function(root, dontCheckRoot) {
        if (!dontCheckRoot && root.className.split(" ").indexOf(className) >= 0)
            return root;

        var children = root.children;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
            var elem = children[i];
            elem = checkChildren(elem);
            if (elem)
                return elem;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Проверяем следующие элементы того же уровня.
    var next = element;
    do {
        var elem = checkChildren(next, next==element);
        if (elem)
            return elem;
    } while (next = next.nextElementSibling);

    // Переходим к родителю (если есть).
    var parent = element.parentElement;
    if (parent) {
        var sibling = parent.nextElementSibling;
        if (sibling)
            return checkChildren(parent.nextElementSibling);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNextElementByClassName(element, className) {
    var temp = element.className;
    element.className = className;
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.'+className);
    var i = [].indexOf.call(elems,element);
    element.className = temp;
    return elems[++i]
}
```

Comment: Тут к коду было бы здорово добавить хоть строку комментария.

Comment: если поиск идёт по классу, временно снимаем все классы с текущего, присваиваем класс который ищем,таки образом встраиваем текущий элемент в цепочку искомых, ищем место текущего в этой цепочке, значит следующий после нашего и есть тот что мы ищем, восстанавливаем текущему его классы и возвращаем то что нашли - элемент или пусто если далее нет нужного.